# For loop function that returns f-string

Tags: python, for-loop, f-string

I am new to python and trying to write a function that accepts a list of dictionaries and returns a new list of strings with the first and last name keys in each dictionary concatenated.

```
names = [{'first': 'John', 'last': 'Smith'}, {'first': 'Jessie', 'last': 'Snow'}]


 def name_function(lst):     
     for name in lst:       
         return f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" 

 names_function(names)
 'John Smith'
```

I wrote a for loop that iterates thru the list of dictionaries and returns an f-string that concatenates first and last name keys in each dictionary, however, the loop fails to iterate beyond the first key and I am hoping some one can point me to the issue.

Comment: a return immediately exits a function and returns the value. you need to store the strings in a list, and return the list at the end. (or opt for other alternatives, yield for example)

Comment: Because you `return` in the first iteration.

Comment: Just `return [f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" for name in lst]` without loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have a loop, you also have a `return` inside the loop. On the first iteration of the list this `return` will be hit and execution of the function will stop there, returning only value on that line — which is a string — rather than the list intended.

You either need to add a list to the function to use as an accumulator before returning —

```
def names_function(lst):  
    names = []      
    for name in lst:       
        names.append(f"{name['first']} {name['last']}")
    return names
```

Or to use a list comprehension

```
def names_function(lst):  
    return [f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" for name in lst]

names_function(names)
```

Both will output

```
['John Smith', 'Jessie Snow']
```

You could also replace the `return` with a `yield` to turn this into a generator. To get all the values you would need to iterate the generator (or call `list` on it)

```
def names_function(lst):     
    for name in lst:       
        yield f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" 

list(names_function(names))
```

Which gives the same result

```
['John Smith', 'Jessie Snow']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wantto get all names:

```
def names_function(lst):
    ret=""
    for name in lst:
        ret += f"{name['first']} {name['last']}\n"
    return ret
```

*or*

```
def names_function(lst):
    return [f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" for name in lst]
```

if you want to create a generator object:

```
def names_function(lst):
    return (f"{name['first']} {name['last']}" for name in lst)
```