# Why does Python `f-string` + inline for loop create a generator when they're passed as parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, generator, f-string

I found this example on the internet

```py
def format_attributes(**attributes):
    """Return a string of comma-separated key-value pairs."""
    return ", ".join(
        f"{param}: {value}"
        for param, value in attributes.items()
    )
```

The syntax of the param passed to the `join` function caught my attention because it's sort of unusual. But it works

Doing some local testing with a minimum codebase I discovered that in:

```py
def foo(res):
    return res

print(foo(f"{s}" for s in ["bar"]))
```

`foo's` syntax is valid and `res` ends up being a generator. However, if I try `f"{s}" for s in ["bar"]` standalone (no function in between), the expression just throws a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

How come the `f-string` + `for loop` is valid and gets converted into a `generator`? What's happening under the hood when invoking `foo` function?

These other questions uses the same syntax:

- [f-strings formatter including for-loop or if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956496/f-strings-formatter-including-for-loop-or-if-conditions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734702/5745962

But I found no comment explaining why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looping construct you're using is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). To write one as a stand-alone expression, you need to add parentheses around it:

```
genexp = (f"{s}" for s in ["bar"])
```

If the generator expression is the only argument to a function, you don't need double parentheses (but you do if there are other separate arguments). Contrast:

```
s = sum(i % 2 for i in some_sequence) # count of odd elements, no extra parentheses needed
```

vs:

```
print(*(i for i in some_sequence if i % 2), sep=",") # print odds, parens are needed this time
```

There's nothing special about f-string used in the generator expression in your code, any expression works the same way.

Comment: I marked this one as the accepted answer because it explicitly states that no parenthesis is needed when a generator is used as a single argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are examples of generator expressions and don't necessarily have anything specific to f-strings or which functions you use with them.

e.g.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(i%2==0 for i in x)
2
```

The example counts the number of even integers in the list.

You can read more about them here: https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions

Comment: I found the article useful. It describes syntax for generators in detail

Answer (score 0):

The f-string has nothing to do with it.

Although a generator expression generally requires parentheses:

```
some_gen = (f"{s}" for s in ["bar"])
print(foo(some_gen))
```

the parentheses can be omitted when the generator expression is the *only* argument to a function call:

```
# These two calls are equivalent.
foo((f"{s}" for s in ["bar"]))
foo( f"{s}" for s in ["bar"] )
```